# how to assign a value to vector <type*> bar*

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

have code like this:
`std::vector <STARTUPINFO*> *si;`

then I init it with:
`si->push_back(new STARTUPINFO);`

And now, how can I refer to an element of the vector?
for example I wanna change `si[i].cb` member

Comment: This is already wrong. You have an uninitialised pointer. Why are you using pointers at all?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I need some vector for my STARTAPINFO handlers, then I can use it for CreateProcess, SuspendProcess, etc. how can I do it correctly?

Comment: So you need a vector. Why did you make a pointer-to-a-vector? Why did you not just make a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>**Note**: `si` have better be initialized somewhere prior to trying to access members of the *pointed-to* container.</sup>

---

You will need to either dereference the pointer, or use some of the available member-functions that provide access to the the elements within, and since the elements are of type `STARTUPINFO*`, you cannot use `.`-notation in order to access members of the elements.

---

#### Examples

```
si->at(i)->cb /* std::vector<...>::at */
```

```
(*si)[i]->cb
```

```
si->operator[](i)->cb
```

Comment: Beware though, using at(i) is not the same as the two other methods, it involves boundary checking and so it is slower. I advice `(*si)[i]->cb`

Comment: @A.S.H thought this was common knowledge, but maybe I should add that to the answer?

Comment: You can do it, but may be it is not necessary since the comment completed it :)

Comment: The trick is that when holding a pointer to vector, almost anyone has the reflex of using ->at, including me, since it is the most obvious choice, until I understood that it slows down my CPU-bound programs.